# BeautifulSoup not parsing arbitrary XML? For example - if there are tags called <body>

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

Working on parsing an xml file with records like:

```
<Message>
    <Subject>some text</Subject>
    <Body>some text</Body>
</Message>
```

but instead of "some text" on the following `BeautifulSoup` gives an error "NoneType has no attribute "text":

```
message.find('body').text
```

I could parse the file after search/replacing the tag name, but it sounds odd.
Is there a way to make `BeautifulSoup` parse any XML structure without dropping records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass `'xml'` as the second argument to `BeautifulSoup`'s constructor:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(your_xml, 'xml')
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I also found that the html parser would lowercase the tag names. I.e. with the html parser `message.find('subject').text` worked and `message.find('Subject').text` did not, but with the xml I had to use correct case.